# CKAN extension deployment not working

Tags: python, ckan

I have developed couple of extensions and never had any problem in deploying to the production server. I did try to installation a new extension today on my production server that works on my dev machine but doesn't work on the production server. I am suppose to see a new menu option as part on this new extension and I don't see that. To test I changed the extension name in the production.ini and I got an expected error (PlugInNotFoundError). I have restarted the apache and nginx. I am running CKAN 2.1.

I did ran the following command on the production server:

python setup.py develop

I got the message that the plugin was successfully installed.

I also included this new plugin in the production.ini file settings.

Restarted both the apache2 and nginx servers.

Still not seeing a new menu option to access the functionality provided by this newly installed extension.

Any help to sort this out be appreciated.

Thanks,
PK

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to clear your browser's cache? Are there any other settings (e.g. `extra_public_paths`) that are different between your dev and production machines?

Comment: Thanks Sean. It is working now. It was a template path problem. I had a test plugin on the dev code that I did not include when deploying to prod server. That test plugin was adding the "template" path of my extension. When I made that part of the actual plugin, it started working. It was a hard bug to detect.